# premake5 way to set UICulture property for windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, premake

I'm using premake5 for visual studio C# projects and could not find a way to set the `UICulture` settings in Visual studio project files. In my project file I have something like:

```
<UICulture>culture</UICulture>
```

Is this possible to set in premake?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't look like there is an API for that right now. Or rather, there is one (see [locale()](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/locale)) but it is only implemented for C++ projects currently.

Probably not a hard thing to add since the API is already there, maybe [open a new issue](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues) or better yet, [submit a pull request](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pulls)?